# What is main difference between FLTK 1.1 and 1.3

Tags: fltk

```
#aptitude search fltk|grep dev

p   libfltk1.1-dev                  - Fast Light Toolkit - development files    
p   libfltk1.3-dev                  - Fast Light Toolkit - development files
```

Why to choose one over another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [version history](http://www.fltk.org/articles.php?L825):

> This is basically FLTK-1.1.10 with extra features, but with an incompatible ABI. The new features include: full UTF-8 Unicode support, which allows left-to-right non-Latin text such as Greek and Cyrillic; new Fl_Tree, Fl_Table and Fl_Native_Filechooser widgets; printing support; a device abstraction layer; and a new progamming manual generated from the code using Doxygen.

As you see, you have now:

- A new ABI that is incompatible with the old
- UTF-8/Unicode
- New tree, table, and filechooser widgets
- Printing
- Device abstraction(new implementation)
- Programming manual from Doxygen

The OP also describes memory usage differences:

> I also noticed 1.1 used 3 MB and 1.3 46 MB

Comment: I also noticed 1.1 used 3 MB and 1.3 46 MB :-O

Comment: Probably they included static library, and/or debugging libraries?